# What does this mean?

Tags: translation

I'm getting this error message.
I need help finding out what this means:

[image]

Comment: The network name is not found.

Comment: @Administrateur The site typically requires users to show some research effort in their posts. The translation should approximate to "cannot find network name".

Comment: -1 Asking 'what is written on this' is absolutely offtopic on zh.se. http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/288/what-translation-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

找不到网络名 - Literally means "couldn't find the network name"

In computer terms, it could mean that you either lost the internet connection or the network the application was going to connect does not exist.